# Another question about ね

Tags: grammar

Can よ be replaced by ね in some cases? For example, in this sentence I read I think ね is interchangeable with よ: "A:で、男役はお好きで らしたんですか 。
B:いやあ、あんまり好きじゃないですね 。" If so, in which cases can you do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to read something like [this article](http://mitizane.ll.chiba-u.jp/metadb/up/SB00228823/kokusaikyouiku_4_11.pdf). It's surprisingly complicated. Here's how they structure it:

```
1．命題内容が聞き手領域の事柄の場合
＜「よ」＞の機能
1−①聞き手の求める新情報告知のための＜注意喚起1＞
1−②聞き手が気付いていない新情報告知のための＜注意喚起2＞
1−③聞き手の知っているべき事柄の告知のための＜注意喚起3＞
1−④聞き手に対する行動要求のための＜注意喚起4＞
＜「ね」「よね」＞の機能
1−①聞き手への命題内容の事柄に対する＜確認要求＞
1−②聞き手への命題内容の事柄に対する＜コメント＞

2．命題内容が話し手領域の事柄の場合
＜「よ」＞の機能
2−① 聞き手に直接関わらない新情報告知のための＜注意喚起5＞
2−② 聞き手に直接関わる新情報告知のための＜注意喚起6＞
2−③ 聞き手に直接関わる意思表明のための＜注意喚起7＞
＜「ね」と「よね」＞の機能
2−① 聞き手への命題内容の事柄に対する＜情報・意思受入れ要求＞

3．命題内容が中立領域の事柄の場合
＜「ね」と「よね」＞の機能
3–①聞き手への命題内容の事柄に対する＜同意・共感要求＞
3−②聞き手への命題内容の事柄に対する＜同意・共感表明＞
```

That said IMO the most important bits is 注意喚起 vs 共感要求. For example, `ダメだよ` would imply "Don't do it", whereas `ダメだね` would imply "Don't think that would work (don't you think?)".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the sense that both can work in that context, though their nuances are different.

In that case, the sentence with ね added feels that the speaker is showing his attitude as if he has just thought twice if he really likes it or not and consequently come to the conclusion, in short, it conveys a nuance of "after all".

On the other hand, よ in that case indicates that the speaker is conscious that what he says doesn't accord to the listener's belief or expectation that the speaker may like 男役.

Answer (score 0):

The implication of よ is emphasizing one's personal opinion.
ね has an implication of seeking agreement.

They can replace each other in any sentence, and that sentence will remain grammatically correct, but the nuance of the sentence will be changed.

Also, you have written 尊敬語 using a colloquial style.　But let's ignore that, because it looks like the sentences are part of a Q&A session, between an interviewer(A) and a young person or a male talento(B). But the way the questions are framed, it seems like a female actor/talento who is portraying a male is being questioned. It's a strange sentence.

A:で、男役はお好きで らしたんですか 。Did you enjoy playing [the part of] a boy?
B:いやあ、あんまり好きじゃないですね 。mmm, I don't really enjoy it, you know.
B:いやあ、あんまり好きじゃないですよ 。mmm, I don't really enjoy it at all!

Finally, じゃない and よ is usually used by males, but not always, everything depends on the situation and context. And ね is usually used by females, but again everything depends on situation and context.

Comment: What do you mean, じゃない and よ are usually used by males? They're gender-neutral. And ね is only 'usually used by females' after a noun with no copula, as in そうね (even then some older male speakers say it).

Comment: It is a big generalization I've made. Maybe, level of politeness would be a better way to describe it.  ではない is more polite than じゃない. And in general, I've always found girls in Japan to be more polite than guys. Maybe girls are just more polite in front of me because I'm a foreigner. But guys are more friendly to me because I'm a foreigner. There is no text book that I know of which makes the claims I've made. It's just something I've noticed over time when talking with Japanese people.

Comment: I feel ではない is more formal than じゃない but I don't feel ではない is politer than じゃない. Politeness and formality are independent axises.
Concerning よ, the Enno Shoiji's link says "Concerning misuse or problematic use in communication of よ, it's revealed that many non-native speakers recognize it as an expression form you use when you inform something in conversation or when you want emphasize your feeling or recognition" (誤用やコミュニケーション上の問題となっている「よ」の使用について、非母語話者の多くは会話の中で何かを伝える時、または自分の認識や気持ちを強調したいときに使用する表現形式であると認識していることがわかった)